# \indent doesn't work as expected in custom nested environments

Tags: environments, indentation, memoir

I have a custom environment that I use as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}

\newenvironment{Myenv}
    {\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{1in}\indent\begin{qshade}}
    {\end{qshade}\end{adjustwidth}}


\begin{document}
TESTTESTTESTTEST.  MORE TEXT.
\begin{Myenv}
Lots and lots of text \par
Including multiple lines and paragraphs.
\end{Myenv}
\end{document}
```

With this definition I DO get my first paragraph inside the shaded square indented.  HOWEVER, I seem to get some extra 'ghost' space, so that the first paragraph in the text is subtly extra indented.  AND in addition `\indent` seems to also add an extra blank line right before the shaded environment.

Any ideas on how to fix the environment?

P.S.  I am deliberately NOT using the `minipage` environment because it doesn't break across pages.  `qshade` from the memoir package DOES break across pages.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to John Kormylo below for the code that replaces `\indent`: namely, replacing the first line of my environment definition by

`{\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{1in}\begin{qshade}\hspace{\parindent}}`.

Thank you everyone else that advised me not to use `\indent`.

The new code gets rid of the extra blank line that `\indent` was fabricating.  HOWEVER, the small extra space at the beginning of the first paragraph still shows up.  Obviously `\indent` is not the culprit of that subtle extra indentation.

Comment: Please provide a complete small document we can compile to reproduce. That is much more useful than a few fragments of code. In order to work on this, somebody has to start guessing all kinds of things they cannot possibly know e.g. how `qshade` is defined etc.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to use `\indent` or `\noindent` in an environment definition but the exact interaction of course depends on the definition of the environments that you have not shown. You could avoid the space by using `\ignorespaces` but not using `\indent` is almost always better,

Comment: And there is always \hspace{\parindent}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Your suggestion works wonders for removing the extra blank line...  The extra space in the first paragraph is still there though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\hspace*{\parindent}` to insert a forced paragraph indent on the first line of the first paragraph. Secondly, in order to get rid (or ignore) any additional spurious spaces, add `\ignorespaces` to the opening definition of `Myenv`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}

\newenvironment{Myenv}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{1in}%
   \begin{qshade}\hspace{\parindent}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{qshade}%
   \end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}
Lots and lots of text \par
Including multiple lines and paragraphs.
\begin{Myenv}
Lots and lots of text \par
Including multiple lines and paragraphs.
\end{Myenv}
Lots and lots of text \par
Including multiple lines and paragraphs.
\end{document}
```

As mentioned spurious spaces may be inserted at the start of the `Myenv` environment. To remove this effect manually, remove `\ignorespaces` and use

```
\begin{Myenv}%
```

Note the use of `%`, as suggested by [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Now, when is more clear, what you like to have, try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{memoir}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\MyIndent
\setlength\MyIndent{\parindent}
\newtcolorbox{Myenvbox}{%
        enhanced,
        arc=0mm,
        frame hidden,
        colback=gray!30,
            grow to left by =-1in,
            grow to right by=-1in,
        breakable}
\newenvironment{Myenv}
    {\begin{Myenvbox}\setlength\parindent{\MyIndent}}
    {\end{Myenvbox}}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

     \begin{Myenv}
\lipsum[2]\par
\lipsum[2]
    \end{Myenv}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I considered using the `minipage` environment in my definition.  I decided against it because it doesn't break across pages, whereas the `qshade` environment from memoir does.

Comment: This you not mentioned in your question ... how do I know then?

Comment: @ltcomdata, see, if new version of my answer fit your wishes.